# Работа в спящем режиме на Android, Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Программа работает, пока устройство активно, как только экран гаснет, программа так же засыпает. Как заставить программу работать в фоновом режиме и не дать ей засыпать вместе с устройством, а продолжать работать? Поиски в интернете приводят описание только для android for java, а как это организовать на C# в VS Xamarin CrossPlatform я понять не могу. Прошу помогите. Хоть пару примеров.

Comment: Это: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/ ?

Comment: Это всё конечно хорошо, но тут пример основан на стандартном классе используемом в Xamarin. А где найти примеры с использованием собственных? Мне нужно, чтоб работала основная функция StartTimerOsnovnoy() которая в фоновом режиме ждёт совпадения текущего времени с основным. Или как проще сказать отключение спящего режима для моей конкретной программы.

Comment: Я не знаток платформы Android, но думаю, что невозможно гарантировать, что система не выгрузит ваше приложение. То есть вам нужно дожидаться нужного момента в сервисе и будить ваше приложение оттуда.

Comment: Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос тут https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Тогда может быть напишите ответ с небольшой смысловой выжимкой этого текста? Для будущих поколений, которых будет интересовать тот же вопрос.

Comment: Я не мастер писать длинных и красивых речей, но попробую на выходных написать.

Answer (score 1):

> Как заставить программу работать в фоновом режиме и не дать ей засыпать вместе с устройством, а продолжать работать?

**используйте [services](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/)**, но разумно. для эвентов есть [intent services](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/intent-services), для хранения состояния и выполнения функций есть [bound services](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services). не используйте sticky и/или foreground service без острой необходимости, это сильно уменьшает заряд батареи.